# Merge multiple sqlite3 identical databases, with different names

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a python script what gives as a result a directory "unpacked" with every time different count of databases with different names.
Now i would like to merge these databases automatically, they have the exact layout!

I have tried to work with the following code, but here I need to change the input name manually, is there a way to do this automatically, so it doesn't matter if it are two databases or 10, it doesn't matter witch name they have as long as they have the exact layout!

```
import sqlite3

con3 = sqlite3.connect("combine.db")

con3.execute("ATTACH 'results_a.db' as dba")

con3.execute("BEGIN")
for row in con3.execute("SELECT * FROM dba.sqlite_master WHERE type='table'"):
    combine = "INSERT INTO "+ row[1] + " SELECT * FROM dba." + row[1]
    print(combine)
    con3.execute(combine)
con3.commit()
con3.execute("detach database dba")
```

Comment: Is there *any pattern at all* to the database files? E.g. they all are located in the same directory and always have the extension `.db`?

Answer (score 1):

You can always pass in a string path as a SQL parameter to an `ATTACH` statement:

```
database_path = "results_a.db"
con3.execute("ATTACH ? as dba", (database_path,))
```

Use this with code to list all database files; for example, using [`glob.glob()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob), and assuming that the database files are all located in the same directory and always have the file extension `.db`:

```
import os
import glob

directory_with_databases = "/path/to/directory"
databases = glob.glob(os.path.join(directory_with_databases, "*.db"))

for filename in databases:
    con3.execute("ATTACH ? as dba", (filename,))

    # use attached `dba` database

    con3.execute("detach database dba")
```

Note that the above assumes that the name `dba` can be re-used for each database file. IF you need attach multiple database at the same time, you'll have to generate the database attachment names too.

If you are using [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) to produce paths, then you'll have to convert the `Path()` instance to a string first:

```
from pathlib import Path

directory_with_databases = Path("/path/to/directory")

for database_path in directory_with_databases.glob("*.db"):
    con3.execute("ATTACH ? as dba", (str(database_path),))

    # use attached `dba` database

    con3.execute("detach database dba")
```

You can always adjust the glob to include arbitrary directories, or to recursively find all matching files; see the documentation for either `glob.glob()` or [`pathlib.Path.glob()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob) for details.

Comment: It are all ".PLSQL" files.
So lets say i have 1.PLSQL ; 2.PLSQL and 3.PLSQL
The idea would be to have a combinded.PLSQL file with the data of all three files.
But nest time it could be the names are 05.PLSQL; abc.PLSQL etc it could be 3 files or 10. Its different all the time.

Comment: As the extensuion maybe would disagree, its a sqlite3 database!

Comment: @TreyK: so use `*.PLSQL` as the glob to match them.

Comment: @TreyK: oops, sorry, too many things requiring my attention, I didn't actually use a glob  :-) Corrected now.

Comment: @ Martijn Pieters

I get the following error:

 for database_path in directory_with_databases.glob("*.PLSQL"):
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'glob'

Comment: @TreyK: The `for database_path in directory_with_databases.glob("*.db"):` loop will only work if `directory_with_databases` is a `pathlib.Path()` object. If you have a string path, then use `Path(directory_with_databases).glob("*.db")` or use the first example.

Comment: @ Martijn Pieters
TNX for your help, i now get the following error, could you please help me again?

con3.execute (combine)
sqlite3.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: PLschemaVersions.ID
INSERT INTO PLschemaVersions SELECT * FROM dba.PLschemaVersions

Comment: @TreyK: that's an entirely different and new problem, so perhaps that's a new question for you to post. We try to keep questions focused on each individual problem.

Comment: @TreyK: the error points out that the `PLschemaVersions` table has a `ID` column that can only contain unique values (it is probably the primary key) but you are trying to insert an ID that already is present in that table.